# How to implement a copy assignment on a doubly linked List?

Tags: c++, constructor, doubly-linked-list, assignment-operator

Im a little confused on how to implement an copy assignment on a doubly linked List. I managed to get the copy constructor working but im sure on the assignment. Im trying to do this without the copy and swap method.

List.H

```cpp
class List 
{
public:
    List();
    ~List();
    List(const List& c);
    List& operator= (const List& t);
private:
    List *Next;
    List *Prev;
    Node *Head;
```

List.cpp

```cpp
List::~List()
{
    Node* move = Head;
    while (move!=NULL)
    {
        Node *temp = move->Next;
        delete move;
        move = temp;
    }
}

List::List(const List& c)
{
    name = c.name;
    Prev = c.Prev;
    Next = c.Next;
    Node* dummy, * current;
    Head= dummy = new Node();
    current = c.Head;
    while (current)
    {
        dummy->Next = new Node(*current);
        current = current->Next;
        dummy = dummy->Next;
    }

    Node* temp = Head;
    Head = Head->Next;
    delete temp;
}

List& List::operator=(const List& t)
{
    Next = t.Next;
    return *this;
}
```

Would I also have to traverse each node in the assignment operator as well?

Edit
So this is what I have now. The problem is when im getting the data from the list it is null.

```
List& List::operator=(const List& that)
{

    if (this != &that)
    {
        while (Head)
        {
            Node* temp = Head;
                Head = Head->Next;
                delete temp;
        }
        Node* dummy, * current;
        Head = dummy = new Node();
        current = that.Head;
        while (current)
        {
            dummy->Next = new Node(*current);
            current = current->Next;
            dummy = dummy->Next;
        }
    dummy->Next = nullptr;
}
return *this;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with copy and swap? It has the added benefit of being exception-safe (assuming your copy is exception-safe).

Comment: `copy-ctor` and `operator=` both are doing shallow copy. Which will can lead to undefined behavior due to `delete`ing same memory from two different objects

Comment: @TruthSeeker The copy-ctor makes a deep copy of the list. Only `Prev` and `Next` whatever they are, are not deep-copied, but they are also not deleted in the destructor, so it should be fine.

Comment: @churill: yes, you are right even though it is assigned it not being deleted. But not sure the significance of `Next` and `Previous`. @Jay any explanation for `Next` and `Previous` usecase?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is YES.

1. **copy-constructor**

```cpp
    List L1;
    List L2(L1);
```

2. **operator=**

```cpp
    List L1;
    List L2;
    L2 = L1;
```

In both the cases, `L1` has to be copied to `L2` and `L1` should be unchanged after copy or assignment. Hence content of every node has to be replicated to newly created node.

Copy Constructor looks something like this:

```
List::List(const List& c)
{
    Node start;
    Node* dummy = &start;
    Node* CurrentNode = c.Head;
    while (CurrentNode)
    {
        dummy->next  = new Node(*CurrentNode);//New node created with content of *CurrentNode
        dummy = dummy->Next;
        CurrentNode  = CurrentNode->Next;
    }

    dummy->next = nullptr;
    Head = start.next;
}
```

And assignment operator like this:

```
List& List::operator=(const List& that)
{
    if (this != &that) //avoid self assignment like List L1;L1=L1;
    {
       while (Head)//Delete exist nodes
       {
           Node* temp = Head;
           Head = Head->Next
           delete temp;
       }

        Node start;
        Node* dummy = &start;
        Node* thatHead = that.Head;
        while (thatHead)
        {
            dummy->next  = new Node(*thatHead);//New node created with content of *thatHead 
            dummy = dummy->Next;
            thatHead = thatHead->Next;
        }
        dummy->next = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: When doing the while(that) i get an exprssion must have bool type error and when creating a new node with the content of *that i get  "no operator matches these operands. wouldnt the While loop need to be while (&that).

Comment: @Jay: I have updated to snippet. Here `that` is `List` and we need to traverse the List Node